# Explicitly allow usage of production API

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I'm exploring WSO2 API Manager platform to use in Open API project. The idea is that we forbid registration in Store and creating users by ourselves. But we also want to give them only Sandbox API as a starting point and then, explicitly allow particular users to consume Production API. Haven't find any information. Is it possible? If yes - where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict the token generation for the Production endpoints by using Workflows. Follow the documentation[1].

You could configure ProductionApplicationGeneration to use `ApplicationRegistrationWSWorkflowExecutor` and SandbobApplicationGeneration to use `ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor`.

With this approach if the subscriber tried to generate a token for production endpoints, it will trigger a human task, which needs to be approved from the Admin Portal.

For your requirement, you could write a custom workflow extension which allows restriction by role or user name. For more information on Writing custom workglow extension please follow [2]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+an+Application+Registration+Workflow

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Customizing+a+Workflow+Extension

Thanks and Regards